# How to find out what page is active, and set include file to reflect active pages?

Tags: php

I have all my navigation stored in an include file. But an issue I've run into is how to set the navigation links to 'active' from the include file?

So that when I'm on the home page, the **Home** link will be activated. And when on the about page, the **About** link will be activated, etc., etc. so on for the other pages.

What would be the best way to find out what page is active, and set the link in the include file to reflect what page is active?

Hopefully that makes sense...

Answer (score 1):

You can use an if statement against the URI, and include required files depending on the current page.

```
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/home.php' ) {
include 'homenav.php';
}
else
{
include 'nav.php';
}
```

Or in the navigation include file

```
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/home.php' ) {
echo '<li class="active"><a href="home.php">home</a></li>' ;
}
else
{
echo '<li class="inactive"><a href="home.php">home</a></li>' ;
}
```

Comment: `__FILE__` is recommended over a $_SERVER var

Comment: Am I supposed to add more to `'/home.php'`? It's not finding as true.

Comment: You could replace == with contains. But if you have contains 'home' and another page is called /newhomesales it will load the home navogation also